# Argument of type 'IIncludableQueryable<Student, List<Student_Teacher>?>' cannot be used for parameter 'source' of type 'IIncludableQueryable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
Warning :

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS8620  Argument of type 'IIncludableQueryable<Student, List<Student_Teacher>?>' cannot be used for parameter 'source' of type 'IIncludableQueryable<Student, IEnumerable<Student_Teacher>>' in 'IIncludableQueryable<Student, Teacher?> EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude<Student, Student_Teacher, Teacher?>(IIncludableQueryable<Student, IEnumerable<Student_Teacher>> source, Expression<Func<Student_Teacher, Teacher?>> navigationPropertyPath)' due to differences in the nullability of reference types."

My Services :    

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var result = await _context.Students
            .Include(navigationPropertyPath: s => s.Parent) // Include the related parent entity
            .Include(s => s.Student_Teachers).ThenInclude(s => s.Teacher)
            .ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

before I add `ThenInclude()`, it's working well and no warning but I can't call the `parent.representative` in my cshtml. After I add `ThenInclude()`, It gives me warning and the code is working well but that give me warning.

When I call `parent.representative` in my cshtml, it gives me warning that it's a nullable referance. I don't want to have a warning.

Please give me explanation.

Answer (score 0):

C8620 is "Argument cannot be used for parameter due to differences in the nullability of reference types. "  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#mismatch-in-nullability-declaration 
You could check carefully about the difference of using nullable mark `?` when defining the class of student and teacher.